# URL change issue after form post in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

how can i manage url in address bar after posting a form or after loading a page after submission.

Is it possible to manage with routing ?

```
<?php
public function index(){
$this->load->view('login');
}

public function login_process(){
....... code......

if($login==true){
$this->load->view('dashboard'); // Url is not changing but view is loaded
}else{
$this->load->view('login');
}

}

?>
```

Comment: you should use redirect method after login or logout or adding

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `redirect()` method from `url` helper , *make sure you load it in controller or in autoload.php*

```
public function login_process()
{
....... code......

if($login === TRUE)
{
    redirect('controller_name/dashboard','refresh');
    /*$this->load->view('dashboard'); */
}
else
{
    redirect('controller_name/index','refresh');
    /*$this->load->view('login');*/
}

}
```

For more :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

You should create another method called `dashboard` and you should redirect to it like following

```
class Example_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function dashboard(){
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    }

    public function login_process(){
        // Your Code
        redirect('Example_Controller/' . (($login==true) ? 'dashboard' : 'index'));
    }

}
```

replace **Example_Controller** with your controller name.

and add following lines in **routes.php**

```
$route['login'] = 'Example_Controller/index';
$route['dashboard'] = 'Example_Controller/dashboard';
```